# possible to have the result of a js button but it make it not refresh

Tags: javascript, forms, button, timer

i have php script to listen to a button that executes each second but i cant get the result of it because it keeps refreshing which i do not want my code for the button is below and the js timer, its simple code.

```
<form id="trigger">
  <input type="submit" id="trigger" name="trigger" onclick="e()" value="click">
</form>
```

and this is the timer plus click;

```
<script>

  
  setTimeout(function () {

    document.getElementById("trigger").submit();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't do

```
document.getElementById("trigger").submit();
```

To get the value from some input box use:

```
document.getElementById('textbox_id').value;
```

and then you could pass the value on to your script using ajax.

If you want to emulate click use:

```
document.getElementById('trigger').click();
```

Your `onclick` function `e()` should `return false` to disable the submit process which will refresh the page.
Also, you should not use the same identifier for multiple things (you from and button are both "trigger").

Comment: hmmm ok ill edit my code to that